# Quoting a papal document is disrespectful?

Tags: discussion

I quoted Pope Pius XI, "Casti Connubii" and I was told that I was being disrespectful.

"we do not debate who is right, and we do play nicely and do not show disrespect to those who believe differently."

I was quoting Casti Connubii.  Seriously.

http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius11/P11CASTI.HTM

[Is the Catholic Church NOT against all birth control?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31340/is-the-catholic-church-not-against-all-birth-control/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake.

It helps if you use the markup to make it clear when you're quoting.. I'll go un-delete it and format it so that it's clear what's a quote and what's your content..

Popes, of course, are not restrained by the guidelines of this site about playing nice and arguing who is right.  Their job description includes, inherently, clarifying who is right in the eyes of the Catholic Church.  They are perfectly free to call others guilty of "criminal abuse on the ground that they are weary of children and wish to gratify their desires" and we're free to quote them.  I honestly thought that was your own words, which would have been in violation of the guidelines here.

I truly apologize for that misunderstanding.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for the undelete.

Comment: This does show the absolute necessity of [indicating and referencing quotes](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) correctly.

Comment: @AndrewLeach And it also shows that the moderators are reasonable people and admit and undo their wrong doings.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What key is that horn in? I mean to say that this is a perfect example to point to for those users that insist the mods are crap.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing. (That "horn" metaphor is new on me.) In order that the point is not diluted, I've deleted that comment; perhaps we could do the same to this latest two as well?